# Записать весь массив в базу данных

Tags: массивы, база-данных, php

Есть код. Выводит все заголовки

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

Нужно вместо echo записать все заголовки в БД, желательно в одну строку. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«В одну строку» – называется [сериализацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). В php сериализировать данные можно разными способами:

1. [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) / [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) — универсальный формат, лучше всего.
2. [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) / [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php) — формат, понятный только самому php.
3. [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php) / [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) — плохой способ, не обрабатывает ресурсы и циклические ссылки, но в вашем случае ОК.
4. [WDDX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDDX) формат: [`wddx_serialize_value()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.wddx-serialize-value.php) и `wddx_deserialize()` – XML хардкор.

Comment: А пример будет?

Comment: Нет.  Что конкретно вам не понятно, как делать?